# The bisector of the exterior angle at vertex C of triangle ABC intersects the circumscribed circle at point D. Prove that AD=BD

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, plane-geometry, angle

The bisector of the exterior angle at vertex $C$ of triangle $ABC$ intersects the circumscribed circle at point $D$. Prove that $AD=BD$.

So what I'm wondering is how to prove this? I've already drawn a diagram but I don't know how to continue from there. Please help!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $$\measuredangle DCB=180^{\circ}-\measuredangle ACD=\measuredangle ABD,$$ which says $$AD=BD.$$

Comment: hi can you please explain why if DCB = ABD, AD=BD?

Comment: @pleasehelpme Because $\measuredangle DCB=\measuredangle ABD$ gives arc DB=arc ACD and from here $DB=AD$.

Comment: Just curious, why did you use directed angles?

Comment: @Shubhangi  I used  properties of inscribed angles because it gives a solution.

Comment: Sorry, I meant is there any configuration issues in this problem ?

Comment: @Shubhangi There are two cases: 1)The segment $AD$  intersects $BC$ (the proof in this case you saw) and 2) The segment $AD$ does not  intersect $BC$. The proof in this case is a similar. In the last case we have reasoning without $180^{\circ}.$

Answer (score 3):

Note that since $CD$ is the external bisector of $\angle ACB$ $ \implies \angle BCA = 180-2\angle DCB \implies \angle ACD= 180-BCD \implies \angle ABD = \angle BCD  $ ( using sum of opposite angles is equal to 180 ) .

Again by cyclic quads, we get that $\angle BCD= \angle DAB$.

Hence we have $\angle DAB=\angle BCD=\angle ABD$ and the result follows.

Comment: I bow before you, 1k+ in just 23 days!

Comment: @Arjun    You don't need to bow or do  something like that .  I just posted questions  and some trivial solutions .